# WebApi and MVC in different projects, share cookies?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cookies, cross-domain

I've separated my WebApi project into a MVC project (http://mydomain.com) and a  WebApi project (http://api.mydomain.com).

My MVC project just manages authentication and service up the views (which use knockoutJS and ajax).

My problem is that the cookies from the MVC project is not sent when requesting information from the webapi domain (***using ajax***). Or rather, during testing I'm using two IIS Express servers on different parts.

The project is going to be deployed do Azure later, so any solution must work between two web sites.

So how can I get those cookies to be sent through? Or should I switch to use some kind of token instead?

## Edit

It works until I add `contentType` to the `$.ajax` request. I get the CORS preflight OPTION then. I answer it 200 with what I think is the correct headers. If I remove that option I get a working request with all cookies again.

**Works**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:54304/Organization/",
    type: "POST",
    data: "$top=10",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
});
```

Do not work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:54304/Organization/",
    contentType: 'application/json', //<--- this triggers preflight
    type: "POST",
    data: "$top=10",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) { console.log(data); }
});
```

Now is that a jquery "feature" or is it how CORS works? What headers should I set? I've tried to reply with:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:51343
```

Answer (score 2):

When you set a cookie, you also set which domain names the cookie should apply to.
Cookies depend only on domain names (and optionally paths); not on what kind of server you have.

In your case, you can set the domain to `.mydomain.com`, which is a wildcard cookie that will be sent to the root domain and all subdomains.

Comment: Does it work for different ports too? It's the Forms Authentication cookie

Comment: Cookies always work across ports.  (this is arguably a design flaw)

Comment: it's strange then because I used the dev tools in Google Chrome and no cookies were included in the request. But I'll check the cookie domain.